# Getting an TypeError: t is undefined in React while accessing commerce.js public key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, typeerror, commerce.js

I was trying to access the commercejs Library's Public Key in React. But i failed to do so and met with this error. I can't understand why i am getting this error.

src\lib\commerce.js

```
import Commerce from '@chec/commerce.js';

export const commerce = new Commerce(process.env.REACT_APP_CHEC_PUBLIC_KEY, true);
```

src\App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Products, Navbar} from './components';
import {commerce} from './lib/commerce';
const App = () => {
    
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        const {data} = await commerce.products.list();
    
        setProducts(data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts();
    })

    console.log(products);

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
            <Products/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

**Error**

TypeError: t is undefined
e
node_modules/@chec/commerce.js/lib/index.js:1

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I see you're a man of culture as well, watching Javascript Mastery on Youtube!

Just check where you created the .env file. It should be stored in the root folder. I had it in my src folder that's how I got this error. If it doesn't work, then go to your commercejs client, login and then at your settings, refresh your PUBLIC API. When you get a new one, just replace it. It should work after this.

Answer (score 3):

Robbie from Commerce.js here. We've had a number of issues from people following this tutorial, so here are a couple of things to watch out for:

1. Make sure your `.env` file is in your project's root folder (the same folder that your `package.json` file is in)
2. Ensure you have installed the `dotenv` package. You can make sure by running `npm install dotenv` or `yarn add dotenv`.
3. Put your public key in your `.env` file under the `REACT_APP_CHEC_PUBLIC_KEY` variable and ensure that your API key is valid. You can fetch your valid API keys from [the Chec Dashboard](https://dashboard.chec.io/settings/developer).
4. Restart your local dev server after making changes to your `.env` file.

Hope this helps

Comment: Installing the dotenv package worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got to same error. You should write terminal  `npm install @chec/commerce.js` and `npm install -g @chec/cli` or visit the website commerce.js => "https://dashboard.chec.io/" .

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue when I watching Javascript Mastery on Youtube. What I did was, disconnect the connection with .env file and just add the public key to commerce.js.This is not the best practice.

`export  const commerce = new Commerce("Your public key", true);`